# JS: async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'am new in JS and had some problems with async function.
I have a function, that return data from MongoDB. I create a promise, and get collection with empty object.

```
async function getRating(item, applicant) {
let arr = await Applicant.find({ proff: item }).sort({ ball: "desc" });
let rating = arr.findIndex(item => item._id.equals(applicant._id));
let spec = await Spec.findById(item);
const el = { spec, rating };
return el;}

router.get("/test", auth, async (req, res) => {
let applicant = await Applicant.findOne({ user: req.user.id });
let ratings = [];
applicant.proff.forEach(item => {
    const rating = getRating(item, applicant)
    .then(rating => ratings.push(rating))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
     ratings.push(rating);
}); 
await res.json(ratings);
});
```

When I check in Postman, this return me array: [{},{},{}]

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO!, can you please tell what are you getting in applicant ?

Comment: I`m not sure, but i can`t find where You cach a response?

Comment: In Applicant I get Collection. Where info about users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `Promise.all`

```js
async function getRating(item, applicant) {
    let arr = await Applicant.find({ proff: item }).sort({ ball: 'desc' });
    let rating = arr.findIndex(item => item._id.equals(applicant._id));
    let spec = await Spec.findById(item);
    const el = { spec, rating };
    return el;
}

router.get('/test', auth, async (req, res) => {
    let applicant = await Applicant.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

    const ratingsPromise = applicant.proff.map(async item => {
        const rating = await getRating(item, applicant);
        return rating;
    });

    const ratings = await Promise.all(ratingsPromise);
    return res.json(ratings);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this part is still async, you have to use await

```
 const rating = getRating(item, applicant).then(rating => ratings.push(rating)).catch(err....
```

Comment: does not work. Now a get empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Async Functions returns promise so you need to use await before getRating.

Comment: use comment for such short answers.